# El ultimo registro se duplica al generar un txt con StreamedResponse Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy utilizando StreamedResponse para descargar unos registros de la base de datos filtrados en formato txt.

Lo hago pero cuando abro el documento me doy cuenta que el ultimo registro se duplica y no se bien el por que. No tengo mucha experiencia con StreamedResponse y espero que me puedan ayudar.

Este es el metodo de mi controlador.

```
   public function descargar(Request $request)
{

    $reportes = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tipo_factura($request->get('tipo-factura'))
    ->tiempo($request->get('date_desde'), $request->get('date_hasta'))
    ->orderBy('created_at' ,'ASC')
    ->get();

    if (request('archivo') == '1') {
        foreach($reportes as $reporte){

            $content='';
            $content.= $reporte->documento.'|';
            $content.= $reporte->tipo_documento . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->bienes . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->ncf . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->ncf_modificado . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->date_comp . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->date_pago . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->monto_servicios . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->monto_bienes . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->monto_total . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_fact . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_retenido . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_sujeto . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_costo . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_adelantar . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->itebis_compras . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->tipo_retencion . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->monto_retenido . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->isr . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->impuesto_consumo . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->otros_impuestos . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->propina . '|';
            $content.= $reporte->forma_pago . '|';
            $content.=  "\r\n";
            print($content);
    }

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallBack(function () use($content) {
        print($content);
    });

    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 
    'DGII_F_606_'.$reporte->rnc_cedula.'_'.'201904'.'.txt');

    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
    return $response;

    } else {

    }



}
```

}

Esto es lo que obtengo en el txt:
12345678910|1|01-Gasto de personal|12345678910|0|2020-04-08|2020-04-02|50000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|||01-Alquileres|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|01-Efectivo|

12345678911|1|01-Gasto de personal|12345678911|0|2020-04-11|2020-04-15|6000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|||01-Alquileres|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|01-Efectivo|

12345678911|1|01-Gasto de personal|12345678911|0|2020-04-11|2020-04-15|6000.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|||01-Alquileres|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|01-Efectivo|

En la base de datos solo hay dos registros pero al generarse el txt el ultimo registro siempre se duplica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví volviendo a vaciar la variable content al final del foreach.